# How do I batch convert material assets to group node assets?

Tags: materials, shader-nodes, asset-browser

Since blender 3.1, it is now possible to create group node assets, making it easier to group shaders and reuse them.
However, most existing assets (blenderkit, ambientCG, etc.) are materials, not group nodes

Once the material is applied, grouping is easy, but time-consuming, as previews must be set manually.

[Question] Is there any add-on that allows batch group node conversion of material assets?

---

[EDIT] My idea of workflow

#### Preparation

1. Drag and drop material assets
2. Group all nodes except for the material output and Mark Asset.
   　(Surface, Volume, and Displacement will be the output node groups)
3. Manually set the preview image of the asset in the group node
   [image]

[image]

#### Use

4. Drag and drop group nodes and connect them with mixed shaders
5. Shaders can be partially reused, e.g. painting textures for fac.
   https://i.imgur.com/xMcnp6e.mp4

Is there any add-on that simplifies this preparation part (1-3)?
This is a question.

Comment: Hello, could you add a diagram explaining more in detail the workflow you're looking for ? Materials and node groups are different in essence, what inputs and outputs do you expect from the action you're looking for ?

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks for the response. I have added my idea of the workflow.